# How to query the resolvconf database?

Tags: networking, resolvconf

The Description of **resolveconf** in it's manual page tells us: *"The resolvconf package comprises a simple database for run-time nameserver information ..."*.

What is clear in the manual page is how to **add** or **remove** information to that database.

But, **How to query it?**.

Answer (score 5):

```
ls /etc/resolvconf/run/interface
```

will list all the pieces of nameserver information that have been added to `resolvconf` database. Their names will usually identify the interface to which they're associated, and possibly other things.

These are all text files, effectively fragments of `/etc/resolv.conf`. So you can view them with any text viewer utility.

For example, on my home gateway system (Debian 9):

```
# ls /etc/resolvconf/run/interface/
eth2.dhclient  eth2.ip6.dhclient  lo.inet  lo.named
```

(If your Linux distribution is new enough to have the `/run` tmpfs filesystem, the directory will most likely be `/run/resolvconf/interface` instead.)

`eth2` is my external interface that gets its configuration via DHCP. The default domain and IPv4 DNS servers provided by my ISP's DHCP server are in file `eth2.dhclient`. The file `eth2.ip6.dhclient` has the same information for IPv6. `lo.inet` contains the domain `search` line I've set locally, and it overrides the default domain set by the ISP. And since I run a local BIND for my private home DNS domain, once BIND has started up, Debian's `systemd` configuration for it will optionally add a `nameserver 127.0.0.1` line as `lo.named`.

Since `/etc/resolvconf/interface-order` file says that `lo` takes priority over anything else, the `search` line from `lo.inet` will always go to the real `/etc/resolv.conf`. If my BIND is running, it will be used as a local nameserver; but if it fails for some reason and `systemd` is unable to restart it, the dependencies in `systemd` configuration will cause the `lo.named` to be removed, and then `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in /etc/resolv.conf will be automatically replaced by ISP's nameservers.

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 18.04, and the `/etc/resolvconf/run/interface` directory does not exist. I did manage to find it under `/run/resolvconf/interface`

Comment: @BenMares Yes, newer Linux distributions with the `/run` tmpfs filesystem generally place the `interface` directory in there like that.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and neither /run/resolvconf... or /etc/resolvconf/... exists.

Comment: @jgomo3 Ubuntu 20.04 might be using `systemd-resolved`, which has integrated support for per-interface DNS settings, so it would not need the `resolvconf` package any longer. Try `resolvectl status`: if it shows you DNS settings, you are using `systemd-resolved`.

Comment: Beautiful. You are correct. resolvectl shows that information. Thank you